# Sending JSON to endpoint with certificate and using private key

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, ssl-certificate

I want to send JSON to an endpoint using vb or C# - easy enough to do. I also think I know how to attach the .CRT file to the request. However, I am unsure how to make use of the .pem private key file? Do I attach that to the request too? I'm using.net framework 4.

Comment: The private key is used to sign the encrypted data You should not give it to anybody!

https://www.pkisolutions.com/accessing-and-using-certificate-private-keys-in-net-framework-net-core/

Comment: Thanks. Any hints/tips on how to do that? Am I signing the data I am sending out?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: You need to create a .pfx file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in a.crt -inkey a.pem -export -out a.pfx
```

and then add that to your request as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069197/add-certificate-on-request-with-restsharp).